# Port a phone number (to Twilio, Plivo, etc.) but still receive calls?

Tags: twilio, sip, voip, telephony, plivo

I have a land line that I'd like to start tracking / recording voice calls to. The number that I use is in the yellow pages, on my website, etc. so I don't want to buy a new number.

If I port my land line number to Twilio or Plivo, etc. will I still receive calls to my office? Will I need to buy a new number from my local phone provider and then forward all calls to my new local number after I've ported my old number? Are there any other solutions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

First up, for anyone who comes to this answer in the future, you can currently only port numbers to Twilio from continental US. Adam, your profile says you're in the US, so I'll continue!

If you were to port your number to Twilio you have a couple of options.

The easiest way is to buy a new local phone number and forward your Twilio calls to it (while tracking/recording them along the way) using Twilio's [`<Dial>` TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial).

Alternatively, you could [set up a PBX and a SIP phone and direct calls towards that using Twilio SIP](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twilio-sip/receiving-sip-how-it-works).